# Django Limiting Session Login Time to N seconds

Tags: django, session

I am trying to limit the amount of time a user can stay logged in for using the settings.py and using Sessions.

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home' 

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi {{ user.username }}!
  <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView # new

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    # now the index function renders the home page
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

Currently it stays logged in and displays the Hi user.username no matter how long the time passes. However refreshing the page after 60 seconds shows not logged in.

Comment: A page that is rendered by Django does not refresh, Django is a server-side framework, it does not update text that is rendered by the server. But it means that after 60 seconds the user is logged out: other actions that require the user to be logged in will not succeed after these 60 seconds.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJWH3dpgMCc I wanted something like this.

Comment: Where it redirects after session runs out.